Proof of a statement in OEIS A260533 about partitions
Defining the coefficient of a partition $p=(p[1]\geq p[2] \geq \dots \geq p[m])$ of $n=p[1]+\dots+p[m]$ as $c(p)=\binom{p[1]}{p[2]} \binom{p[2]}{p[3]}\dots\binom{p[m-1]}{p[m]}$ A260533  states that the sum of the coefficients of the set $P(n,k)$ of all partitions of $n$ with leading term $p[1]=k$  equals $\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$
Could you please give me a reference or a proof of this fact?

Better to use p_i ($p_i$) instead of p[i]. The second is how a programmer writes it, not a mathematician.

Usually (but not always) something is called a coefficient because there is a polynomial involved, and the sum of the coefficients evaluates the polynomial with all variable equal to $.1.$ Just a guess.

This recently appeared at MSE 4940765.

@Marko Riedel: Thank you for this link. This answers my question.
